# Generalized alignement index of classic Lorenz system?

Tags: nonlinear-dynamics

I am reading about generalized alignment index (GALIs) as chaos indicator. However, I have been looking around for a while now to see an example of this applied on to the classic Lorenz attractor, but to my surprise I couldn't find any!

I would greatly appreciate if anyone knows the existence of such an example and can point me there!